# page redirect, passes referring url on form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a page that when it is loaded redirects to another page (using js). This other page has a form on it. I want this form (that is linked to from other pages in the site) on submission to pass the referring url along with the rest of the form input.

I hope that makes sense. I'd be grateful for any direction.

Comment: Do you want to pass the data entered in the form from one page to another ?

Answer (score 0):

You can include `HIDDEN` input with `HTTP_REFERER` server variable inside your form:

```
<form>
    ....
    <input type="hidden" name="httpReferer" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];?>">
    ....
</form>
```

Just note what documentation says:

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.